# Learning policy where action involves discrete and continuous parameters

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, actor-critic-methods

Typically it seems like reinforcement learning involves learning over either a discrete or a continuous action space. An example might be choosing from a set of pre-defined game actions in Gym Retro or learning the right engine force to apply in Continuous Mountain Car; some popular approaches for these problems are deep Q-learning for the former and actor-critic methods for the latter.

What about in the case where a single action involves picking both a discrete and a continuous parameter? For example, when choosing the type (discrete), pixel grid location (discrete), and angular orientation (continuous) of a shape from a given set to place on a grid and optimize for some reward.
Is there a well-established approach for learning a policy to make both types of decisions at once?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! So, are you looking for a setting where at each time step the agent takes multiple actions or, equivalently, an action that is composed of other sub-actions?

Comment: In the specific context I am considering, the agent will take a single action that consists of placing a shape with a given orientation and size on a grid. This involves concurrently choosing among a set of discrete shapes, anchor locations, and a continuous rotation all at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent paper: [Continuous-Discrete Reinforcement Learning for
Hybrid Control in Robotics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00449.pdf) published by DeepMind that aims to solve this problem, as stated in the abstract:

> Many real-world control problems involve both discrete decision variables – such as the choice of control modes, gear switching or digital outputs – as
>   well as continuous decision variables – such as velocity setpoints, control gains or
>   analogue outputs. However, when defining the corresponding optimal control or reinforcement learning problem, it is commonly approximated with fully continuous
>   or fully discrete action spaces. These simplifications aim at tailoring the problem
>   to a particular algorithm or solver which may only support one type of action
>   space. Alternatively, expert heuristics are used to remove discrete actions from
>   an otherwise continuous space. In contrast, we propose to **treat hybrid problems
>   in their ‘native’ form** by solving them with **hybrid reinforcement learning**, which
>   **optimizes for discrete and continuous actions simultaneously**.

The idea is that they use a *hybrid policy* that uses a Gaussian distribution for the continuous decision variables and a categorical distribution for the discrete decision variables. Then, they extend the [Maximum a Posteriori Policy Optimisation (MPO)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06920.pdf) algorithm (also by DeepMind) to allow it to handle hybrid policies.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUqQDLQXb7I&feature=youtu.be) is a video showing how they used the resulting *hybrid MPO* policy in a robotics task, where in addition to the continuous actions, the robot can choose a discrete action which is the control mode to be used (coarse vs. fine).